# Suggested edit bug

Tags: bug

Am I banned from suggesting edits?  What's going on?

> [image]

Comment: You should be, after trying to gratuitously edit Nico-nico-Ni into someone's salutation.

Comment: @Ward-ReinstateMonica but I don't think I met the criteria for the ban.

Comment: You have had a majority of your edit proposals declined, you have a history of attempting, to propose identical or similar edit proposal multiple times.  I know I have brought my concerns about this behavior to the moderators in the appropriate chat room.  [In fact, your last edit proposal, was recently rejected.](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/972515).  Based on the timeline, if that’s when you were banned, would have been a 30 day ban.  Only you can tell when your ban started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed banned from suggested edits. The ban will be lifted in approximately two weeks.

I cannot see a specific edit that resulted in  the ban, but your accepted/rejected edits seem focused on an incredibly narrow set of answers or questions. It may be worth looking to try and diversify your contributions to the site.

Comment: I thought edit bans only last for a week.  Why is it more than a week?

Comment: The length of automatic review bans, double each iteration, if you fail an audit.  If you were banned for a week earlier then it would have doubled to 2 weeks.  However, moderators can also issue manual bans, if they feel you are suggesting or approving edits, that are not valid.